# How can I exchange all the NAs in the columns for their medians?

Tags: r, dplyr, missing-data, sapply, valuestack

I would like to exchange all NA values in the columns for the respective medians

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
varA <- c(15,10,8,19,7,5,NA,11,12,NA)
varB <- c(NA,1,2,3,4,3,3,2,1,NA)
df <- data.frame(id, varA,varB)

median(df$varA, na.rm=TRUE)
median(df$varB, na.rm=TRUE)

df1 <- df

# Columns to be modified with Median in place of the NA

col <- c("varA", "varB")                           

df1[col] <- sapply(df1[col],  
                              function(x) replace(x, x %in% is.na(df1), median[col]))
df1
```

Error in `[.default`(df1, col) : invalid subscript type 'closure'

Comment: You're anonymous function `replace(x, x %in% is.na(df1), median[col]))` has all sorts of problems: Use `x` only, no `df1` or `col`.  And you can't use `[` on functions, `median[col]` makes no sense and causes your error. Change it to ``replace(x, is.na(x), median(x, na.rm = TRUE))` and it has a chance of working.

Answer (score 2):

We may use

```
library(zoo)
df[col] <-  na.aggregate(df[col], FUN = median)
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` + `tidyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
mutate(varA = replace_na(varA, median(varA, na.rm = TRUE)),
       varB = replace_na(varB, median(varB, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting it, I was just editing the post

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which is similar to your original attempt.

```r
df1[col] <- apply(df1[col], 2, \(x) ifelse(is.na(x), median(x, na.rm = TRUE), x) ) 
df1
#>    id varA varB
#> 1   1 15.0  2.5
#> 2   2 10.0  1.0
#> 3   3  8.0  2.0
#> 4   4 19.0  3.0
#> 5   5  7.0  4.0
#> 6   6  5.0  3.0
#> 7   7 10.5  3.0
#> 8   8 11.0  2.0
#> 9   9 12.0  1.0
#> 10 10 10.5  2.5
```